# Invalid selector: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '{website}'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting

> 'invalid selector: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
>   Failed to load '{website}''

error when trying to run my tests on Chrome. I am running Chrome `version 76.0.3809.132` and using Chromedriver `version 76.0.3809.126.` This issue just started appearing last week.

When debugging the tests, the website loads and the abstract test base starts running. It fails as soon as it tries to invoke the @beforeTest methods.

Here is the stack trace for the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to to run BeforeTestCase for: testcases.analysis.stressscenarios.byriskfactor.TestColumnsDisplayed
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testlisteners.TestListenerFactory.lambda$runListenersFor$10(TestListenerFactory.java:25) ~[fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testlisteners.TestListenerFactory$$Lambda$7/460702435.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testlisteners.TestListenerFactory.runListenersFor(TestListenerFactory.java:18) ~[fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testcases.TestCaseScript$Test.lambda$test$5(TestCaseScript.java:65) ~[fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testcases.TestCaseScript$Test$$Lambda$257/1435820321.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testcases.TestCaseScript$Test.executor(TestCaseScript.java:93) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testcases.TestCaseScript$Test.test(TestCaseScript.java:65) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testsuites.ParameterizedJUnit4RunnerBuilder$ParameterizedJUnit4Runner.run(ParameterizedJUnit4RunnerBuilder.java:88) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testsuites.ParallelTestSuite.access$200(ParallelTestSuite.java:31) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testsuites.ParallelTestSuite$1.lambda$evaluate$13(ParallelTestSuite.java:144) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testsuites.ParallelTestSuite$1$$Lambda$252/319426406.run(Unknown Source) [fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) > [?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  at testlisteners.TestListenerFactory.lambda$runListenersFor$10(TestListenerFactory.java:24) ~[fubar.jar:SNAPSHOT]
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2]  ... 34 more
>   [14:50:29]    [Step 1/2] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '{website}'.

Tried downgrading Chromedriver with no results. Tried restarting the machines with no success. Verified this is not caused by having too many orphaned driver instances.

Here is the code it is running while it fails:

```
public static void runListenersFor(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType, Class<?> testClass){
        Set<Method> listeners = TestListenerFactory.findListenersOfType(annotationType);
        listeners.forEach( (Method m) -> {
            ArrayList<String> listeningTo = Arrays.stream(getClassesToListenTo(m.getAnnotation(annotationType))).collect(
                    ArrayList::new, (resp, elem) -> resp.add(elem.getName()), ArrayList::addAll
            );
            if (listeningTo.size() == 0 || listeningTo.contains(testClass.getName())) {
                logger.info("Invoking @"+annotationType.getSimpleName()+":" + m.getName());
                try { m.invoke(m.getDeclaringClass().newInstance()); }
                catch (Throwable t) { throw new RuntimeException("Unable to to run "+annotationType.getSimpleName()+" for: " + testClass.getName(), t); }
            }
        });
    }
```

It is failing on `try { m.invoke(m.getDeclaringClass().newInstance()); }`

Comment: The error is clearly shown as invalid selector. If you can post the html & code, we may be able to help.

Comment: At the point in the code, it is not even trying to select anything. It has already logged into the app and just stops working. It runs perfectly in other browsers, so the selector is not the issue. And rerunning a few times in Chrome will usually get it to pass and this error only appears sometimes.